# Neo4j duplicating nodes in MERGE call in Node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm having an issue where Neo4j is duplicating nodes from a set of Merge calls. here is the cypher I am using:

```
    MERGE (b:TRIGGER {name: $rname})
    MERGE (c:FIELD {name: $target})
    MERGE (b)-[:MODIFIES]->(c)
    RETURN b, c
```

This cypher is being sent from a function in node.js as it loops through an array of possible relationships.

Here is the full function:

```js
async function addTarget(rname, target, neouser, neopass,bolturi) {
  // console.log("Adding Target");
  const driver = neo4j.driver(
    // "bolt://localhost",
    bolturi,
    neo4j.auth.basic(neouser, neopass)
  );
  const session = driver.session();

  try {
    await session.writeTransaction(async txc => {
      var result = await txc.run(
        `MERGE (b:TRIGGER {name: $rname})
         MERGE (c:FIELD {name: $target})
         MERGE (b)-[:MODIFIES]->(c)
         RETURN b, c`, {
          rname: rname,
          target: target
        }
      )

      result.records.map(record => {
        // console.log(`b: ${record.get('b')}, c: ${record.get('c')}`);
      })
    })
  } finally {
    // console.log("finally");
    await session.close();
    await driver.close();
  }
}
```

```js
async function addTrigger(rname, trigger, neouser, neopass, bolturi) {
  // console.log("adding trigger");
  const driver = neo4j.driver(
    // "bolt://localhost",
    bolturi,
    neo4j.auth.basic(neouser, neopass)
  );
  const session = driver.session();

  try {
    await session.writeTransaction(async txc => {
      var result = await txc.run(
        `MERGE (b:TRIGGER {name: $rname})
         MERGE (c:FIELD {name: $trigger})
         MERGE (b)<-[:ACTIVATES]-(c)
         RETURN b, c`, {
          rname: rname,
          trigger: trigger
        }
      )
      result.records.map(record => {
        // console.log(`b: ${record.get('b')}, c: ${record.get('c')}`);
      })
    })
  } finally {
    // console.log("finally");
    await session.close();
    await driver.close();
  }
}
```

And here is the loop I am calling it from.

```js
          var objRules = ruleList;
          for (var i = 0; i < objRules.length; i++) {
            var rname = objRules[i].triggername;
            var trigger = objRules[i].trigger;
            addTrigger(rname, trigger, neouser, neopass, bolturi)
            for (var j = 0; j < objRules[i].targets.length; j++) {
              var target = objRules[i].targets[j];
              addTarget(rname, target, neouser, neopass, bolturi)
            }
          }
```

I know I am using Merge correctly, because every time I have used this before it worked perfectly. I am binding the variables to a node first, using Merge, and then using Merge for the relationship. This should create a unique node for each Field ID or Trigger only if it does not already exist and then use those nodes in the relationship Merge.

Thank you for any help or ideas.

The two differences I see now is that I am using the latest version of Neo4j 4 and Node.js.

edit: Fixed question. I accidentally put Match in the question when it is Merge. The code was correct. 
edit 2: added addTrigger function

Comment: Your code is using `MERGE`, but your question keeps asking about "match". Aren't you actually asking about `MERGE`?

Comment: fixed. I don't know why I typed Match when it is an issue with Merge.

Comment: Can you show, in your question, the `addTrigger()` code as well? Also, your code is *extremely* inefficient, as it is creating/using/closing a new driver per `rname, target` pair. You should be passing a *list* of `rname, target` values instead, and your Cypher code should use [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) on that list to perform the equivalent functionality in a *single* transaction with a single driver.

Comment: @cybersam addded. It is basically a copy/past of the add Target code with minor changes. 

I'm sure that there are easier ways of doing this. I'll look into the unwind.

Comment: You should also try to combine the addTrigger() and addTarget() Cypher code. It is possible that your heavy use of concurrent write transactions involving the same nodes is exposing some weak points in the neo4j server. If you did everything in a single transaction, that might prevent the issue.